# Angular2: Third Party code and Monkey Patching

Tags: angular, typescript, requestanimationframe

In a project we are using a third party library (that isn't a angular2 library - just plain old javascript). It just runs some background tasks using tickless intervals and `requestAnimationFrame` callbacks. However, as soon as we have angular2 in the game, it starts to execute the change detection; this is something I don't want! Even more, it is causing protractor to wait forever and so times out :s

It seems that `runOutsideAngular` is the closest thing, but as for what I understand it would only be "running outside" for one "spin". For instance, if one would call `requestAnimationFrame` as an outside function; and inside this `requestAnimationFrame` another `requestAnimationFrame` is called, this would run insideAngular again; right? Although, when I read the documentation on Angular2
[it states](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/NgZone-class.html) that:

> Any future tasks or microtasks scheduled from within this function
>   will continue executing from outside of the Angular zone.

Even more, when would I call `runOutsideAngular` for the third party library, because the library kicks in long before angular2 is even known to my webapp?